# Completable of RxJava is not completing or erroring

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have been using Rxjava for more than a few years but never tried other operators than Observable. 
Recently I have been architecting a new app for which I have gone through few articles on how to make best use of RxJava.
I have been using MVP for my project and familiar with interactors. 
I have written one base Interactor which does background work for me. Below is the source code for that.

```
abstract class CompletableInteractor<PARAMS>(
private val executionThread: ExecutionThread,
private val postExecutionThread: PostExecutionThread) {

private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()
protected abstract fun buildUseCase(params: PARAMS?): Completable

private var isInProgress = false

fun execute(observer: CompletableObserver, params: PARAMS? = null) {
    val subscribeWith = this.buildUseCase(params)
        .subscribeOn(executionThread.scheduler) //io
        .observeOn(postExecutionThread.scheduler) // AndroidMainThread
        .subscribeWith(observer)}

}
```

Now here is my Interactor code which is trying to work with this Completable use case

```
class ApplicationSearchInteractor @Inject constructor(
private val dataService: DataService,
@Named(ComputationThread.computation) executionThread: ExecutionThread,
postExecutionThread: PostExecutionThread) : CompletableInteractor<String>(executionThread, postExecutionThread) {

override fun buildUseCase(params: String?): Completable {
    return dataService.doSomeCompletable(params)}}
```

Now here is the implementation of the DataService

```
class DataUploadRepository @Inject constructor(){

override fun doSomeCompletable(name: String?): Completable {
    name?.let {
        return Completable.complete()
    } ?: kotlin.run {
        return Completable.error(NullPointerException())
        }
    }   }
```

Now What I am trying to do here is writing test case for the ApplicationSearchInteractor and trying to 
make the Completable.complete() and Completable.error test cases passed by passing name null and some no null values which do not happen.

Even I have created a test app putting all these things together calling interactor from the presenter. But none of the callbacks of the CompletableObserver are getting called.
I am completely blank now what are the mistakes I am making as I did the same thing with Observable and everything was great with it.
Presenter code

```
class DataUploadPresenter @Inject constructor(private val applicationSearchInteractor: CompletableInteractor<String>) {

fun registerApplications(callingApp: String) {
    applicationSearchInteractor.execute(applicationFoundObserver, null)
}


private val applicationFoundObserver = object : CompletableObserver {
    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {

    }

    override fun onComplete() {
        print("hello")
    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        print("error")
        //e.printStackTrace()
    }

}}
```

When I try to complete or error Completable it doesn't call its respective callbacks of CompletableObserver

**EDIT: I observed something strange now. the kotlin's print methods are not getting printed hence it appeared to me that the callbacks are not triggering. My bad but don't know why these prints methods are not printing on an android studio.**

Comment: @Gustavo edited the questions with more details

Comment: `doSomeCompletable` implementation is missing in this question.

Comment: @SanlokLee thanks for pointing out. I have edited the question now.

Comment: You are using `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` which, when run with standard Schedulers, introduce asynchrony hence the test method will return before the signals reach the observer. What value does `executionThread.scheduler` have?

Comment: @akarnokd it is using Schedulers.computation()

Comment: @akarnokd If i forget about the unit tests, this is not working for a normal flow

Comment: The listed code should work as far as I understand it. Do you have by any chance something like `startWith { someObservable }` in your actual code? Otherwise it would be more revealing if you posted a project demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @akarnokd i am not doing anything else with the Completable instance. Cant put entire project.

Comment: Looks like you have to put many `doOnSubscribe { println("OnSubscribe-" + System.currentTimeMillis()) }` into the flow in `execute` to see where things stop. Similarly `doOnEvent { println("OnEvent: " + it + " " + System.currentTimeMillis()) }` would reveal where events disappear. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is required so the logcat doesn't hide repeating lines.

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks i will add System.currentTimeMillis() and see how it behaves